# How do I call an external iss script and use the functions within from a main Inno Setup script under Code section?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have an Inno Setup script with a code section for some basic stuff. But I also have another Inno Setup script file (.iss) that deals with Windows services specifically. I would like to call these functions/procedures directly from my main script. So how do I `#include` the `services.iss` file into my main script so that I can call its functions from the `Code` section?

I've seen some examples on the net indicating how to split the file section using this method, which is great, but I want to be able to split the code section using common code scripts between installations. I could find mention of it here and there, but nowhere does it tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 6):

As you have mentioned yourself, use the [`#include` pre-processor directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=include).

If you have a common code file like `common.pas`:

```pascal
procedure CommonProcedure;
begin
  // ...
end;
```

You can include it into the main `.iss` script like:

```pascal
[Code]

#include "common.pas"

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  // Calling procedure included from the common.pas
  CommonProcedure;

  Result := True;
end;
```

---

The extension does not really matter. I've used `.pas`, as the file it's purely a Pascal (Script) code. But if you prefer `.iss`, it's your choice. Though then, syntactically it would be more appropriate to include section name into the file:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CommonProcedure;
begin
  // ...
end;
```

And include the file out-side of the `[Code]` section:

```pascal
#include "common.pas"

[Code]

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  // Calling procedure included from the common.pas
  CommonProcedure;

  Result := True;
end;
```

This approach even gives you greater flexibility, e.g. in case you need some support files for your code:

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "InnoCallback.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

procedure CommonProcedure;
begin
  // ...
end;
```

*(Though it's just a matter of coding style. Technically, it does not really matter, as the sections can be mixed in any way. So you can have `[Code]` section, followed by `[Files]` section, followed by another `[Code]` section).*

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you